# Why is setTimeout() not asynchronous when used with an event handler?

Tags: javascript

In this code, I have a function 'loop' that performs a CPU-intensive calculation. So, I execute it using setTimeout() with a 0ms delay to make it work asynchronously. However, when using it within an event handler, it blocks the code, and I cannot use immediatly the other event.

```
const startTimer = document.querySelector('#startTimer');
const btnShowMex = document.querySelector('#btnShow');
const h2 = document.querySelector('#testo');

const timerOra = Date.now();

let num = 0;

function loop() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 999_000_000; i++) {
    num += 1;
  }
  console.log(`end loop`);
}

startTimer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(loop, 0);
});

btnShowMex.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('message');
});
```

if I use it without event handlers, I get the correct asynchronous behavior

```
console.log('start');
setTimeout(loop, 0);
console.log('end');

-->start
--->end
--->end loop
```

Given that setTimeout() is asynchronous, I expect to have all the click events available.

Comment: The output from your code is as you expect when I run it: https://jsfiddle.net/gwonrvyb/. Can you please create an example snippet in your question which fully demonstrates the behaviour you're seeing. Also, what browser are you using? It may be due to the implementation of the JS engine.

Comment: if you put a `console.log` line after the `setTimeout(loop)` call you'll see it executed before the loop actually ended. So it's behaving according to expectations

Comment: A timeout with 0 seconds doesn't really make anything asynchronous, it's just synchronous code run later.

Comment: @DBS is a wrong practice but yet the setTimeout will return immediately

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461267/js-loop-blocking-browser-ui

Comment: @DiegoD I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The `setTimeout` will immediately create the timer, but with `0` as its second property, it won't run immediately, it will wait until the next "cycle", which gives people the impression of asynchronicity.

Comment: @DBS I was traveling on a different line with my comments... I meant that the `setTimeout` call doesn't block the execution of the next instruction. It returns immediately and anything following will be executed now. Of course the callback will be executed when the given time passed. But that's ignoring the internals

Answer (score 7):

You have misunderstood the concept of *asynchronous* in Javascript.

JavaScript is a single-threaded language. This means that only single thing can happen on the single thread (main thread) in JavaScript. With `setTimeout`, you schedule a callback to be executed at some later time BUT it doesn't mean that it will execute in some background thread. Once the timer expires, it will execute on the main thread, blocking every other code until your callback is executed completely.

Any long-running code, such as a loop, will block the main thread and until that loop ends, nothing else can execute. This results in freezing of the UI in web apps.

From [MDN - Introducing asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing):

> Asynchronous programming is a technique that enables your program to start a potentially long-running task and still be able to be responsive to other events while that task runs, rather than having to wait until that task has finished. Once that task has finished, your program is presented with the result.

In the case of `setTimeout`, you start a timer and once that expires, the callback you provided is pushed on to the call stack. Once that happens, that callback executes like any other code in JavaScript. If it contains any long-running code, main thread will be blocked. While the timer is running, the main thread is free to execute other code. This is what makes `setTimeout` asynchronous.

Note: You can execute code in a separate thread using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Good explanation, but that MDN quote is very misleading. As it is written, it fully suggests threaded behaviour.

Comment: @connexo Yeah, it can be reworded for better explanation. That is why I added further explanation under the quote. Note to OP: In the case of `setTimeout`, the "long-running task" is the timer, not the callback. The timer is handled in the background but the callback is executed on the main thread.